# How to manually force continuing in ILM policy or updating executing phase for index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several times an index will get stuck due to mis-configuration or get an error while testing out the ILM API. I should hopefully get this all resolved but what bothers me is once an index gets stuck like this I don't know how to progress it.

Example: 
I had a policy for warm phase

```
"warm": {
    "min_age": "1d",
    "actions": {
      "readonly" : { },
      "forcemerge": {
        "max_num_segments": 1
      },
      "allocate": {
        "include" : {
          "box_type": "hot,warm"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It would get stuck saying "Waiting for [5] shards to be allocated to nodes matching the given filters". Issue is I have no box_type of hot or warm. So how could I then fix this misconfiguration and continue the ilm? Is it possible to update the executing policy on an index? Or to assign a new policy to index but change it's lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question is largely answered by:

To unblock waiting for allocation issue is to remove the setting on the index itself
For example, remove from the index setting the following:
"index.routing.allocation.include.box_type": "hot,warm"

There's also an advanced API to move an index to another step manually
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/ilm-move-to-step.html#_path_parameters_16

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'allocate' section from the ILm definition above, as there are no nodes in your cluster matching that condition. Then the warm phase will execute just the forcemerge and readonly actions.

After that, you can issue a ILM retry using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-lifecycle-error-handling.html#_retrying_failed_index_lifecycle_management_steps

When facing ILM problems, the ILM explain api (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ilm-explain-lifecycle.html) should lead you to the root of the problem.

For more detailed informations please have a look on this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/_updates_to_executing_policies.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-lifecycle-error-handling.html

Comment: This doesn't work because the index continues to execute the policy it started with, so even if I remove the 'allocate' section from the policy the index continues to execute the older version of the policy. This is the part which I don't know who to get that 1 index unstuck. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/_updates_to_executing_policies.html

Comment: Please see at the very bottom of the page we both linked. It seems, that a index operation will help. If not, have you tried to remove and reassign the ilm policy to the index?

Comment: In the example in the doc the index always remains in the phase of policy 1   regardless of the policy updates, it only then moves to warm phase version 3 because the rollover condition of version 1 (max_docs:1) is achieved. But my issue is that it's stuck in the phase to begin with.
Removing and reassigning doesn't work because it starts the ILM cycle all over again in the hot phase.